# Python in django models.py

Tags: python, django, lambda, sum

This works in python IDLE

```
class A:
    b = 0

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.b = value

obj1 = A(1)
obj2 = A(2)
obj3 = A(3)
k = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
result = sum(i.b for i in k)
print str(result)
```

But this doesn't work for django/python

```
from django.db import models

class Flatbar(models.Model):
    width = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()

    def Area(self):
        return self.width * self.height

class Section(models.Model):
    flatbars = models.ManyToManyField(Flatbar)

    def Area(self):
        return str(sum(f.Area for f in self.flatbars))
```

Why is this not working and how would I do this using a lambda function?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute for a `ManyToManyField` yields a manager, and you made `Area` a method.

```
return str(sum(f.Area() for f in self.flatbars.all()))
```

Comment: Your's probably right about the manager .all() but I have tried this and it's not working =[

Comment: Sorry about my edit.. I didn't know you could do that! Well, in that case, this should work verbatim Pizzaguru. Make sure you're replacing the correct method.

Comment: One more thing: AFAIK, according to python convention, only class names are capitalized, method names are not. I'd rename the Area method to area(self)